# Failed to compile with 2 errors in ./resources/sass/app.scss

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-mix

I want to create authentification system in laravel 6

**after these commandes:**

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel=6.0 ecommerce-laravel --prefer-dist
composer require laravel/ui="^1.0" --dev
php artisan ui vue --auth
npm install && npm run dev
```

**i get this error :**

[image: l]

Answer (score 0):

- Did u run npm install inside ur project folder ?
- Otherwise, Try remove the npm cache by running this command `npm cache clean` then run `npm install`